# Spring + Angular - How to download a server generated file

Tags: angular, spring, swagger, springfox

I have an endpoint on my server that is supposed to return a json file generated on the fly. This is what I wrote:

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/{id}/json", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
    @ApiOperation(value = "Animal data as a json file", authorizations = {@Authorization(value = "JWT")})
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getAnimalFile(@PathVariable("id") String id) throws JsonProcessingException {
       Animal animal = animalService.getAnimal(id);
       return ResponseEntity.ok().header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=" + animal.getId() + ".json").body(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsBytes(animal));
    }
```

The @ApiOperation allows swagger to include this operation when it generates my client libraries.
However, this is what ng-swagger-gen creates in the Angular side:

```
  /**
   * @param id id
   * @return OK
   */
  getAnimalFileUsingGET(id: string): __Observable<string> {
    return this.getAnimalFileUsingGETResponse(id).pipe(
      __map(_r => _r.body as string)
    );
  }
```

This is not ideal because I can't download the file generated by the server this way. In my component I have an exportJSON method:

```
exportJSON(): void {
   this.animalService.getAnimalFileUsingGET(this.animal.id).subscribe(content => {
       console.log(content); // prints the json content but I don't have the filename
   });
}
```

I looked at other answers here on SO and they say use `window.open(SERVER_ENDPOINT_HERE)` but that doesn't work because my endpoints use authentication (JWT).

Is there a way to either:

- make ng-swagger-gen realize this is a file with a filename and provide me both when I subscribe to the Observable it returns
- or bypass swagger and use Angular to download the file using the server provided filename and authentication?

The ideal solution would be to change something in the server side so that swagger generates the correct response type where I can get both the file and the filename from the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
 getAnimalFileUsingGET(id: string | number): Observable<Blob> {
    return this.http.get(`/stats/export/${id}`, {responseType: 'blob'}); // Adjust your GET accordingly
  }
```

Also, you will need to install FileSaver.js

```
npm i file-saver@1.3.2
```

And finally, use it like this:

```
 import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .

 exportJSON(): void {
     this.animalService.getAnimalFileUsingGET(this.animal.id).subscribe((blob: Blob) => {
       saveAs(blob, 'export.json');
     });
 }
```

EDIT 1:
To be able to access the `Content-disposition` header, you need to instruct Angular Http client to do some changes in the response.

```
  getAnimalFileUsingGET(id: string | number): Observable<HttpResponse<any>> {
    return this.http.get(`/stats/export/${id}`, {observe: 'response', responseType: 'json' })
  }
```

Then you can Subscribe like this:

```
exportJSON(): void {
this.animalService.getAnimalFileUsingGET(this.animal.id).subscribe((resp: HttpResponse<Blob>) => {
           console.log(resp.headers.get('content-disposition'));
           // Extract filename from header
           const filename = '';
           saveAs(resp.body, filename);
   });
}
```

Comment: Thank your for your answer, unfortunately this does not use the filename provided by the server

Comment: @Tecnogirl Since your endpoint is returning a JSON file, you can change the response and include the filename and the data. Then you can create the Blob manually like this `const blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(jsonObject)], {type : 'application/json'});`

Comment: I don't want to "contaminate" the Animal entity with something that is used for an endpoint. it should be possible to access the filename from the content-disposition header

Comment: @Tecnogirl You still need to find a way to extract the filename from the header (maybe a regexp?)
But at least now you should have access to it.

Comment: You can pass the filename in the headers in the backend and extract the file name in your typescript code like this.HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add("fileName", "testfile124.txt");